# How to check which process is occupying the most disk i/o in solaris

Tags: solaris

I am trying to check which process is taking up most disk i/o on my solaris server as it is behaving very much slow. Need help.

iostat -xtc

```
             extended device statistics                    tty         cpu
```

device    r/s    w/s   kr/s   kw/s wait actv  svc_t  %w  %b  tin tout  us sy wt id
sd1      75.9  979.9  113.3 3524.9  0.0  5.4    5.1   0  69    0   53   1  2  0 97
nfs1      0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0  0.0  0.0    0.0   0   0

Comment: See https://serverfault.com/questions/266245/on-solaris-how-can-i-tell-what-processes-are-doing-disk-i-o-on-a-particular-dev

Answer (score 0):

It is quite hard, iotop script from Brendan Gregg can help you.
Here is the script:
http://www.brendangregg.com/DTrace/iotop

Here is the explanatory paper:
http://www.brendangregg.com/Solaris/paper_diskubyp1.pdf